The database cannot be opened because the VBA project contained in it cannot be read when open .accdb
https://i.sstatic.net/57JO73HO.png
Message error
I received a request from a customer who wanted to run the Access system on both 32bit and 64bit environments.
Example code:
' Windows  API‚

#If Win64 Then
' 64Bit
Declare PtrSafe Function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Flags As LongPtr, ByVal ProcessID As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Declare PtrSafe Function Process32First Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As LongPtr, ByRef ProcessEntry As PROCESSENTRY32) As LongPtr
    
Declare PtrSafe Function Process32Next Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnap As LongPtr, ByRef ProcessEntry As PROCESSENTRY32) As LongPtr
    
Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As LongPtr

#Else
Declare Function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Flags As Long, ByVal ProcessID As Long) As Long


Declare Function Process32First Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, ByRef ProcessEntry As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
    
Declare Function Process32Next Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnap As Long, ByRef ProcessEntry As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
    
Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As Long

#End If
I got an error when converting accdb file from Access 32 bit to 64 bit. I have done the conversion rules and it ran successfully on Access 64bit. But the problem appeared when I used the same file to open it again on Access 32bit, it showed VBA error.
What's more strange is that I have a machine running a 32bit environment and it can still open the file normally (only that one machine).
I have experimented with Access's option settings but all to no avail.
Reproduction:

Open .accdb on Access32bit
Edit VBA for 64 bit compatibility
Test ( Access 32bit => OK;  Access 64bit => OK ; Back to Access 32bit => False)

*When I open the file (the error occurs when I open it on 64bit Access environment)
the references are no longer fully added. But the Visual Basic For Application reference is unchanged " C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1 ".
=> I guess this missing reference is due to the VBA files not being readable leading to the reference declarations not being passed
File is not corrupted
enter image description here
File corrupted (after running on Access 64bit)
enter image description here

What did you do to convert to 64 bit? What "conversion rules"? You cannot expect a 32bit system to be able to run 64bit code, so sharing whih us what conversion technique you have used is important

This is the document I refer to.
https://t-yumi.jp/gengo/access/202001220029121518.html#toc3
Basically what I do is add "PtrSafe" after "Declare" and replace "Long" with "LongPtr" with the library usage declarations

Just replacing all Longs with LongPtr is bound to lead to problems. You'll actually need to asses what should be a pointer and what should be an ordinary long (DWORD, most enums, etc.)

Maybe but my problem here is
My test sequence:

Access 32bit => OK ;
Access 64bit => OK ;
Back to Access 32bit => False

I don't know if it's because Access64bit has encoded the file in some way that makes it impossible to open it on Access 32bit!
However, the strange thing is that a colleague's computer in my company can open the error file (only 1 computer so far).  This makes me feel confused

Are both 32-bit and 64-bit systems running the same build?
You must create a 32-bit accde using a 32-bit installation of Access, just as you must use Access 64-bit to generate a 64-bit accde.
Does your code compile without errors on both bitnesses?
For anyone else, this has been crossed posted all over the place:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/the-database-cannot-be-opened-because-the-vba/9be195f3-238d-4be9-9535-a677c7f15675
https://www.utteraccess.com/topics/2066245?post=unread

This error normally is indicative of corruption.  You could try creating a new blank database and importing everything into it, then adding the necessary VBA references, compiling the code, ...
I'd personally use a backup, prior to the issue, and import everything into a new blank db.
You may like to review: https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/the-vba-project-cannot-be-read.326838/

Thank you so much !
Before posting the question I searched all sources on google but there was no solution for me.
I run the same content for both 32bit and 64bit. The error only appears when I run the application on 32bit after running it on 64bit.
I tried to recreate the database but it didn't work. The error still appears when I run it on 32bit after running it on 64bit.
*The important thing here is that there is 1 of my colleagues' machines (only 1 machine so far) he can run the accdb file that I have the error. After he runs it I can open the file without any problem.

"Reposted"—please don't do this. Edit the existing question to make it on-topic, clear, and high-quality so it can be reopened.

These 64-bit declarations are all wrong. For example, if you look at CreateToolhelp32Snapshot it takes in two DWORD values = ordinary Long and not LongPtr, but returns a HANDLE = LongPtr.

Also note that structs like PROCESSENTRY32 will need adjustment for 64-bit compatibility. Because these declarations are wrong your application will have undefined behavior, meaning anything could happen including corruption of the database file.

I edited the data type of the parameters ( LongPtr to Long) as you suggested but it still didn't work. They still give errors when going from Access64bit to Access32bit
